# Python Requests - 403 for POST after successful login

Tags: python, web-scraping, session, cookies

I'm trying to scrape a Sierra Wireless RV55 hotspot webpage for certain network performance metrics. I originally found [this logger for a similar hotspot model](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/scream/blob/master/Sierra-RV50X-logger.py) that was the inspiration for my own code.

With the code below, I can login successfully to the webpage. After authenticating, I want to scrape some metrics. Getting these in the browser looks to be a POST method to a CGI script with the desired metrics requested from a payload of comma-delimited integers. For testing, I just want to use 261 (RSSI). I can see this is the correct payload value easily just from the 'preview' in the DevTools network console.

```py
login_url = 'http://192.168.13.31:9191/xml/Connect.xml'
login_payload = '''<request xmlns="urn:acemanager">
<connect>
<login>{}</login>
<password><![CDATA[{}]]\x3e</password>
</connect>
</request>'''.format(login, password)

# Request metrics with ID POST to cgi script
req_url = 'http://192.168.13.31:9191/cgi-bin/Embedded_Ace_Get_Task.cgi'
# Any payload values give the same 403
req_payload = '261'

with requests.Session() as s:

    # First, authenticate this session. This works correctly
    l = s.post(login_url, data=login_payload)
    print("Login response: ", l.status_code, " ", l.reason)
    print("Login cookies: ", l.cookies)
    print("Login headers: ", l.headers)

    # Get RSSI, 403 every time, cookies? Headers?
    r = s.post(req_url, headers=req_headers, data=req_payload)
    print("RSSI Request status code: ", r.status_code, " ", r.reason)
    print("RSSI cookies: ", r.cookies)
    print("RSSI headers: ", r.headers)
```

With output like so:

```
Login response:  200   OK
Login cookies:  <RequestsCookieJar[<Cookie csrf-token=e48c66b3a305a6a456290795a6188f23 for 192.168.13.31/>, <Cookie token=3423cd55662cee3d2853d4b723d0b2f5 for 192.168.13.31/>]>
Login headers:  {'Set-Cookie': 'token=3423cd55662cee3d2853d4b723d0b2f5; path=/; SameSite=strict, csrf-token=e48c66b3a305a6a456290795a6188f23; path=/; SameSite=strict', 'Date': 'Wed, 31 May 2023 14:51:45 GMT', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}

RSSI Request status code:  403   Forbidden
RSSI cookies:  <RequestsCookieJar[]>
RSSI headers:  {'Refresh': '0; url=http://192.168.13.31:9191/', 'Date': 'Wed, 31 May 2023 14:51:45 GMT', 'Connection': 'close', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Content-Type': 'text/html'}
```

Could this be due to the headers not matching or the cookies missing from the POST call? I thought with sessions the cookies were supposed to be persistent throughout. Even attempting to manually set the cookies with `cookies = s.cookies` does nothing.

I've tried many permutations of adjusting request headers, setting cookies, and using the DevTools in chrome to figure this out. I'm pretty stumped on where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.